# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when using GET method on API

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, callback

After I added a middleware for authorization and roles purposes I cannot get data from protected endpoint.

this route is responsible for fetching all coming visits

```
router.get('/all', authorize, VisitController.getAllVisits);
```

`authorize` is a middleware responsible for checking wether user is logged in and has proper role(s):

```
module.exports.authorize = (req, res, next) => {
    roles = ['super_admin']
    if (typeof roles === 'string') {
        roles = [roles];
    }

    verifyToken(req, res, next),

    const role_ = req.get('Role')
    if (roles.length && !roles.includes(role_)) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    next();
}
```

and when I call Get on this endpoint with `super_admin` role via Postman first I got this error (404 not found):
`Cannot GET /api/visits/all`

and on server side I got:

```
(node:5920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\jan\Desktop\hairdresser-service\service-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\jan\Desktop\hairdresser-service\service-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\jan\Desktop\hairdresser-service\service-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Visit.find.then.documents (C:\Users\jan\Desktop\hairdresser-service\service-api\controllers\visitController.js:127:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

`getAllVisits` function:

```
module.exports.getAllVisits = (req, res) => {
    Visit.find().then(documents => {
        return res.json({
                message: 'Visits fetched successfully',
                visits: documents
        });
    });
};
```

`verifyToken` function:

```
module.exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']
    if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ')
        const bearerToken = bearer[1]
        if(bearerToken == 'undefined' || bearerToken == '') {
            res.json({
                status: 403
            })
        }
        req.token = bearerToken
        next()
    } else {
        res.json({
            status: 403
        })
    }
}
```

So what is the problem here? Some say it's because of sending many responses, but I don't do that.

Comment: show `verifyToken`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande added right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` is telling you that you're ending the request twice. That's happening because in `module.exports.authorize` you're calling `verifyToken` and ignoring that it's ending the request or calling `next`.

`verifyToken` should be separated from `authorize`. An easy fix would be to export an array of middlewares

```js
module.exports.authorize = [
  verifyToken,
  (req, res, next) => {
    roles = ['super_admin']
    if (typeof roles === 'string') {
        roles = [roles];
    }

    const role_ = req.get('Role')
    if (roles.length && !roles.includes(role_)) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    next();
  }
];
```

Now your code will call first, `verifyToken`, and it `next` is called, it will go to the middleware that's checking the roles.